# Merging Observable with Itself

Tags: rx-java

I'm using RxJava to figure out if x amount of time has elapsed since an event. The logic I'm using is basically to delay an event by x, merge it with the main event stream and check if two events are the same. The only case where two events will be exactly the same is if the delayed event is the only event that occurred since the original event.

The code is something like this:

```
sourceObservable
    .mergeWith(
        sourceObservable
            .filter(Event::isOneEvent)
            .delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    )
    .scan(Event.OtherEvent(), (event1, event2) -> event1.equals(event2) ? Event.TimeOut() : event2)
    .filter(Event::isTimeoutEvent)
```

The issue is, when this stream is subscribed to, only the inner observable gets the events. I reckon this is because the observable is cold. I've tested the same with a `PublishSubject` which works but I don't want to use that if there is a better solution.

Comment: You probably want to use `Observable.publish()` and create a connectible observable that can be shared by several subscribers. This way you can distribute the events.

Comment: Why not use `debounce` (or one of the `throttleXXX` operators)? It will fire if the last event wasn't followed by another event within the given time window. If no other event happened, the original event is emitted. If you are interested the time between events, use `timeInterval()`.

Comment: @akarnokd I looked at throttle, must have misunderstood how it worked. Thanks, I will use that.

Comment: @ReutSharabani I'll investigate that... Thanks.

Comment: Ok... so those suggestions take care of most of my problems. Thanks a lot guys. I have another problem but that's unrelated this so I'll asked that as a separate question.